# mongodb group by with all keys

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a huge collection, i m trying to group by all documents' key so I can detect the similar ones.
the documents could have different keys or a similar one.
is there anything that group by all fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$$ROOT` to refer to the entire document:

Sample collection:

```
db.getCollection('sample').insert({"x":"1","y":"2","z":"3"})
db.getCollection('sample').insert({"x":"1","y":"2","z":"3"})
db.getCollection('sample').insert({"x":"1","y":"2","z":"3","t":"4"})
db.getCollection('sample').insert({"x":"4","y":"5","z":"6","t":"7"})
```

And the query:

```
db.sample.aggregate([
  {$project: {_id: 0}}, // remove the _id field
  {$group: {_id: '$$ROOT', count: {$sum: 1}}}, // group by the entire document
  {$match: {count: {$gte: 2}}} // get all duplicates
])
```

Comment: just another question: i've found that i'd about 40 fields but is there any way to exclude some fields (i have some like primary keys)

Comment: You can add them to the `$project` stage, just like `_id`.

Comment: the prolbm that the req doesn't work with $project
i've to remove it to have result ..